# Parse clipboard without Loop [Autohotkey]

Tags: autohotkey

AHK Novice here.

I have a spreadsheet with data that is used to fill forms in an application in IE.

Perhaps there is a better way, but is it possible to parse the clipboard without a Loop function?

I've created this code to copy the selected range in excel and parse the clipboard, pasting each value down a column:

```
^`::

Send, ^c ; this copies the column in Excel
WinActivate, ahk_exe iexplore.exe ; activate browser
Sleep 30
Loop, parse, clipboard, `n, `r
{
 Send, ^a   
 SendRaw, %A_LoopField%
 Sleep 30
 Send, {down}
 Sleep 30
}
clipboard = 
Return
```

The issue is the data cannot always be pasted down a column.  Sometimes a pattern would be something along the lines of:

```
Send, ^c ; copy the selected data in Excel
WinActivate, ahk_exe iexplore.exe ; activate browser
Sleep 30
;paste first data item
SendInput, {down}{tab}
;paste second data item
SendInput, +{tab}{down}
;paste third data item
SendInput, {down}
;paste fourth data item
SendInput, {down}
;paste fifth data item
```

Also, is there a way to activate a window (excel spreadsheet) based on what the name starts with? Basically, I have several reports (where the data comes from) that, for example, start with XXX then have an identifying reference number (e.g. XYZ 31259875, XYZ 57896547).  Only one of these reports would be open at a time.

Please excuse my ignorance and thank you in advance!

Comment: How would the script know when to go down or sideways? I don't think the loop is your problem, it's figuring out how detect how the script should navigate the sheet.

Comment: @Sidola I was thinking that I could have several scripts, one for each pattern (like the example above).

Comment: Assuming you know exactly how many lines you're working with, you could use [StrSplit()](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/StringSplit.htm) and turn it into an array, then access the array at different lines.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use:

```
ComObjGet()
```

What you can do is get the Excel COM object, then it's just like vba:

```
 MyWorkbook := ComObjGet("Somepath here")
 row = 0
 column := 1 ;Column A as an example    
 Loop, 50 ;Just an example for the loop
 {
      row:= row + 1
      Cell:= MyWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(row, column).text
      WinActivate, ahk_exe iexplore.exe
      ...your other events
  }`
```

Also I'd strongly suggest using IE's COM object too, that way you can use the element's ID or something similar to get control. Example:

```
;Get Pointer to IE
For ie in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
 {
    if (ie.LocationName="SomeWindowNameHere") and InStr(ie.FullName,  "iexplore.exe")
    {
        break
    }
 }
```

And finally...

`ie.getelementbyid("SomeElementID").value:=Cell`